# adb install - Failure [0]

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

What does `Failure [0]` mean?

Occurs on Android L, Galaxy Note 4 latest AT&T firmware

```
~root$ adb install wanderlust.apk 
4975 KB/s (185182205 bytes in 36.346s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/wanderlust.apk
Failure [0]
```

Detailed log via logcat... Observer no longer exists?

```
D/PackageManager(  992): New package installed
D/PackageManager(  992): doPostInstall for uid{10276}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_UNBIND
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] SEND_PENDING_BROADCAST
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] POST_INSTALL: observer{909958069}
D/PackageManager(  992):           Handling post-install for 1
D/PackageManager(  992): delete codoeFile: 
D/PackageManager(  992): result of install: 1{909958069}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] CHECK_PENDING_VERIFICATION
D/PackageManager(  992): remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_UNBIND
D/PackageManager(  992): START_PACKAGE_INSTALL: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           originPath{/data/local/tmp/test.apk}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] INIT_COPY: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           idx{0}
D/PackageManager(  992):           for_user{UserHandle{-1}}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_BOUND: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           for_user{UserHandle{-1}}
D/PackageManager(  992): copyApk
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_RECONNECT
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] PROCESS_PENDING_INSTALL: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992): currentStatus{0}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] POST_INSTALL: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           Handling post-install for 2
D/PackageManager(  992): result of install: 0{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_BOUND: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           for_user{UserHandle{-1}}
D/PackageManager(  992): copyApk
D/PackageManager(  992): remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] PROCESS_PENDING_INSTALL: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992): currentStatus{-18}
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] POST_INSTALL: observer{276791339}
D/PackageManager(  992):           Handling post-install for 3
D/PackageManager(  992): result of install: -18{276791339}
I/PackageManager(  992): Observer no longer exists.
D/PackageManager(  992): [MSG] MCS_UNBIND
```

Comment: get more detailed information about the error with `adb logcat -d -s PackageManager:*`

Comment: Any help or insight?

Comment: you get your actual error code from the PackageManager log (which is `-18`, see the `result of install: -18{...}`  line) then you look up the error code in `PackageManager.java` to get name of the constant (`INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR`) then you go google it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error "result of install: -18" installing an app both from Android Studio and apk, on a Samsung with a probably badly mounted SD card.
I solved the problem removing

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

from the manifest.